# Sorting Arrays alphabeticly

Tags: java, android

How can I sort an array in Java/Android alphabetically?
After that I want to provide the ordered array to a `ListView`.

Comment: [Arrays.sort()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort(java.lang.Object[])).

Answer (score 3):

Arrays.sort() should do the trick

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html

Comment: <T> void
 sort(T[] a, Comparator<? super T> c)
          Sorts the specified array of objects according to the order induced by the specified comparator  ?

Answer (score 3):

it can be done just using

```
Arrays.sort(myarray);
```

Answer (score 1):

For more complex sorting see [Comparator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html)

Example:

```
Arrays.sort(some_array, new Comparator<SomeObject>() {
@Override
public int compare(SomeObject entry1, SomeObject entry2) {
    return entry1.getSomeData().compareTo(entry2.getSomeData());
}
```

});

Answer (score 0):

Objects that implement the Comparable interface (like Strings) have a natural ordering (as defined by its compareTo method) so you can just use [Arrays.sort()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html):

```
Arrays.sort(yourArrayOfComparables);
```

It will directly sort the array and will not make a copy.

If you want a more specific sort that isn't considered "natural" you can create a Comparator for that object:

```
Comparator<MyObject> comp = new Comparator<MyObject>() {
    public int compare(MyObject obj1, MyObject obj2) {
        //Code here
    }
}
Arrays.sort(yourArrayOfObjects, comp);
```

The rules for [Comparators](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) and [Comparables](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html) (where the first object is the object itself) is: return a negative if the first object is less than the second, positive for the other way round and 0 if they're equal.